# how to remove first 3 character of every word in each line

Tags: python

I have a data file and I want to delete first 3 character of each word in each line

Here is the example of my file:

```
input 
"13X5106,18C2295,17C1462,17X4893,14X4215,16C3729,14C1026,END"
"17C2308,14C1030,15C904,20C1602,17C1017,18C1030,END"
"13C2369,20C1505,18X4245,15C1224,14C1031,12C885,17C936,END"
"11C3080,13C4123,16C1180,14C1141,15C932,18C1467,END"

output
"5106,2295,1462,4893,4215,3729,1026,END"
"2308,1030,904,1602,1017,1030,END"
"2369,1505,4245,1224,1031,885,936,END"
"3080,4123,1180,1141,932,1467,END"
```

I tried to code but the output is not shown the way I want.

```
file1 = open('D:\pythonProject\block1.txt','r')

data = file1.read()

remove_char = [sub[3:] for sub in data]

print(remove_char)
```

Comment: Change `file1.read()` to `file1.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `file1.readlines()`, then you will need to split by comma. The only problem is that it may introduce an end-of-line character at the end. This is because of your `END` string at the end of each line. But this is easy to get rid of as shown below:

#### Code:

```
file1 = open('D:\pythonProject\block1.txt','r')
remove_char = [[s[3:] for s in sub.split(',')] for sub in file1.readlines()]
for the_list in remove_char:
    print(the_list[0:-1])
```

#### Output:

```
['5106', '2295', '1462', '4893', '4215', '3729', '1026']
['2308', '1030', '904', '1602', '1017', '1030']
['2369', '1505', '4245', '1224', '1031', '885', '936']
['3080', '4123', '1180', '1141', '932', '1467']
```

Comment: there is no point in useing `readlines` here... just use `file1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
data = ["13X5106", "18C2295"] # this is a sample list of strings

print([code[3:] for code in data  if code != "END"])
```

This will print the same list with all strings with the first three chars discarded skipping the "END" string:

```
['5106', '2295']
```

Comment: You have not added a check for "END".

Answer (score 0):

I read the file with `f.readlines` and got rid of the `"` on each line.
Then each word is split by `,` and processed as `word[3:]`.

```py
with open("...", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = map(lambda x: x.replace('"',"").strip("\n").split(","), lines)

res = [] 
for line in lines:
    new_line = [] 
    for word in line:
        if word != "END":
            word = word[3:]
        new_line.append(word)
    res.append(",".join(new_line))
res = "\n".join(res)
print(res)

# Output
"""
5106,2295,1462,4893,4215,3729,1026,END
2308,1030,904,1602,1017,1030,END
2369,1505,4245,1224,1031,885,936,END
3080,4123,1180,1141,932,1467,END
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to print each line in for loop:

```
file1 = open('D:\pythonProject\block1.txt')
data = file1.readlines()
for sub in data:
    line = [j[3:] for i in [eval(sub)] for j in i.split(',')[:-1]]+[eval(sub)[-3:]]
    remove_char = f'"{chr(44).join(line)}"'
    print(remove_char)
```

Or generator expression:

```
remove_char = '\n'.join('"'+chr(44).join(j[3:] for i in [eval(s)]
              for j in i.split(chr(44))[:-1])+','+chr(44).join([eval(s)[-3:]])+'"'
              for s in open('D:\pythonProject\block1.txt').readlines())

print(remove_char)
```

Output:

```
"5106,2295,1462,4893,4215,3729,1026,END"
"2308,1030,904,1602,1017,1030,END"
"2369,1505,4245,1224,1031,885,936,END"
"3080,4123,1180,1141,932,1467,END"
```